# Formula to identify if project is active between to specific dates based on start and end date of project

Tags: excel-formula

Could someone help me build a formula to calculate if a project was active/current during a particular year based on a start and end date (some times the end date is missing as the project is still ongoing so it should be counted as active from start date to the date of the report. I need to know how many projects were active in 2022 and 2023 but sometimes I also need to do the same formula but for a particular FY like 2022-23 (April to April). Thank you so much in advance.

tried `=IF(AND(J2>DATEVALUE("31/12/2022"),I2<DATEVALUE("01/04/2024")),TRUE,FALSE)` as I had used a variation of this in the past which seemed to work but this doesn't and I can't remember what I used. Many projects have a blank end date which means they are current from whatever time they started to the date of the report but can't seem to add this to the formula successfully either. Sorry but my formula knowledge is a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=AND([@StartDate]<=Filter_endDate,
     OR([@EndDate]>=Filter_startDate,[@EndDate]=""))
```

The second part of the `AND` checks if the EndDate is empty or greater than the Filter_startDate.

[image]